# Dynamic SQL statement with nested selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, insert, nested

I have two tables, `transforms` and `design_fields`. `transforms` has a field called `transforms`, and `design_fields` has a field called `transform`. `design_fields` contains all of the `transform` rows, in which some are duplicates. `transforms` (table) `transform` (column) is what I am trying to populate with the `transform` values from `design_fields`.

I've been doing some of them by hand using the following queries.

Get list of `design_fields` `transform` that are not in `transforms` (table) `transform` (column):

```
select transform, COUNT(*) as trans_count
from design_fields
where transform not in (
    select transform
    from transforms
    where transform is not null
)
group by transform
order by trans_count desc
```

Insert `design_field` `transform` into `transforms` (table) `transform` (column) + other stuff.

```
insert into transforms (field_id, transform_name, transform)
select field_id, logical_name, 'TRANSFORM NAME GOES HERE' as transform
from fields
where field_id in (
    select field_id
    from design_fields
    where transform = 'TRANSFORM NAME GOES HERE'
)
```

Though this method works for the most part, there are over 600 rows that I would need to do this in. This is why I'd like to use a dynamic query to insert all the rows from that listing into the `transforms` table.

Here is what I have so far (disclaimer: I'm new to dynamic queries):

```
select 'insert into transforms (field_id, transform_name, transform)
    select field_id, logical_name, ' +
        (select distinct transform
        from design_fields
        where transform not in (
            select transform
            from transforms
            where transform is not null ))
    + ' as transform
    from fields
    where field_id in (
        select field_id
        from design_fields
        where transform = ' + 
            (select distinct transform
            from design_fields
            where transform not in (
                select transform
                from transforms
                where transform is not null )) +
    ')'
```

This statement returns an error message saying that it returned more than 1 value. I understand why this is, I just don't know any other way to do this.

Any help, including pointers for future use of dynamic queries would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about using EXEC statement where you can make its parameter a string.  The exec statement would call a stored proc passing the insert params you want.  for example:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `EXEC` statement where you can make its parameter a string.

The exec statement would call a stored proc passing the `insert` parameters you want.  for example:

```
Declare @SQL varchar(600);
Set @SQL = 'select * from yourTable';
EXEC(@SQL);
```